# jQuery event to get all data from object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using SpreadJS and I need an event to be triggered whenever the object (spreadsheet) changes so that all the data in it is sent to the server:

```
function (){
    var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
    var activeSheet = spread.getActiveSheet();

    activeSheet.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.EditEnd, function (sender, args) {
        var dados = JSON.stringify(spread.toJSON());
        console.log(dados);
        $.ajax({
            // ...  
        });
    });
}
```

The data in 'dados' includes everything in the spreadsheet except the last changed cell. How to fix this?

I tried to include this inside the event handler but the result is the same:

```
var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
```

Comment: Maybe, a 0 duration setTimeout? i'm not sure when the editEnd is happening, but maybe it's happening right before the content is saved, similar to how a keydown event on an input works.

Comment: I don't see any documentation on the wijspread widget in the wijmo documentation. Edit: There it is: http://wijmo.com/docs/spreadjs/API/symbols/$.wijmo.wijspread.Events.html#event:EditEnd that's *very* useful...

Comment: I got the documentation from this link: http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/SpreadHClientUG/webframe.html#Spread~$.wijmo.wijspread.Events~EditEnd_EV.html

Comment: A 0 duration settimeout fixed it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a button on the top of spreadsheet,then entering all ur data in spreadsheet,click on button ,then u get all the data u wanted in jsonformat...

```
    $("#button1").click(function(){
  var dados = JSON.stringify(spread.toJSON());
console.log(dados);});
```

Comment: This isn't really and answer to this question - the OP was asking about an event driven approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "ValueChange" or other events and use "arg" to get the change.

For example: **arg.newValue** will get the last change on this cell, **arg{row, col}** will get the changing cell location. Hope this will help you.

Here is events in SpreadJS:
http://wijmo.com/docs/spreadjs/API/symbols/$.wijmo.wijspread.Events.html

```
    activeSheet.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.ValueChanged, function (e, arg) { 
        var r = arg.row;   
        var c = arg.col; 
        var v = arg.newValue;
        $.ajax({
        // ...
        });                                 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the *ValueChanged* event

```
var spread = $("#ss").wijspread("spread");
var activeSheet = spread.getActiveSheet();

activeSheet.bind($.wijmo.wijspread.Events.ValueChanged, function (sender, args) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(spread.toJSON()));
});
```